# How to unit test an ActionResult that returns a ContentResult?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, unit-testing, actionresult

I want to unit test the following ASP.NET MVC controller Index action. What do I replace the actual parameter in the assert below (stubbed with ?).

```
using System.Web.Mvc;
namespace MvcApplication1.Controllers
{
    public class StatusController : Controller
    {
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            return Content("Hello World!");
        }
    }
}


[TestMethod]
public void TestMethod1()
{
    // Arrange
    var controller = CreateStatusController();

    // Act
    var result = controller.Index();

    // Assert
    Assert.AreEqual( "Hello World!.", ? );
}
```

Answer (score 22, accepted):

use the "as" operator to make a nullable cast. Then simply check for a null result

```
[TestMethod]
public void TestMethod1()
{
    // Arrange
    var controller = CreateStatusController();

    // Act
    var result = controller.Index() as ContentResult;

    // Assert
    Assert.NotNull(result);
    Assert.AreEqual( "Hello World!.", result.Content);
}
```

Answer (score 11):

I like creating assertion helpers for this sort of thing. For instance, you might do something like:

```
public static class AssertActionResult {
    public static void IsContentResult(ActionResult result, string contentToMatch) {
        var contentResult = result as ContentResult;
        Assert.NotNull(contentResult);
        Assert.AreEqual(contentToMatch, contentResult.Content);        
    }
}
```

You'd then call this like:

```
[TestMethod]
public void TestMethod1()
{
    var controller = CreateStatusController();
    var result = controller.Index();

    AssertActionResult.IsContentResult(result, "Hello World!");    
}
```

I think this makes the tests so much easier to read and write.

Comment: That's a great idea Seth. I have quite a few of the ContentResult unit tests to code so this will help on trying to keep to the DRY philosophy .

Comment: @Nicholas: Glad you found it helpful. Other helpers I have are `AssertActionResult.IsRedirectTo(result, url)` and `AssertActionResult.IsViewResult(result, viewName)`.

Answer (score 4):

You cant test that the result is not null, that you receive a `ContentResult` and compare the values:

```
[TestMethod]
public void TestMethod1()
{
    // Arrange
    var controller = CreateStatusController();

    // Act
    var result = controller.Index();

    // Assert
    Assert.NotNull(result);
    Assert.IsAssignableFrom(typeof(ContentResult), result);
    Assert.AreEqual( "Hello World!.", result.Content);
}
```

I apoligize if the Nunit asserts aren't welformed, but look at it as pseudo-code :)