# MVC3 unit testing

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, unit-testing

Im new to mvc 3 and I'm doing unit tests. I'm testing a search action method. This method returns an action method that contains a generic list of some type. How do I test if the model data returned is of that specified type?
Please help.

Answer (score 0):

In your test method you do a type assertion after you have obtained the search results in a variable. Here is an assert for NUnit:

```
var searchResults = SearcherUnderTest.Search("TestKeyword");

Assert.IsInstanceOfType( Type expected, object searchResults );
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean that you want to test the type of T in a List? If so then look at this question: [How to get the type of T from a member of a generic class or method?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/557340/c-sharp-generic-list-t-how-to-get-the-type-of-t)

Or do you need help with writing a unit test for an action? Then: [How to unit test an ActionResult that returns a ContentResult?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2335552/asp-net-mvc-how-to-unit-test-an-actionresult-that-returns-content)

Testing with Nunit, it usually looks like this when testing search results:

```
[Test]
public void Search_ShouldReturnAListOfOrders()
{
    var result = _controller.Search("searchParameter") as MyViewModel ;

    Assert.That(result, Is.Not.Null);
    Assert.That(result.SearchResults, Is.Not.Null);
    Assert.That(result.SearchResults.Count, Is.GreaterThan(0));
}
```

Comment: Lets say i have a class screenmodel and screensmodel. screens model contains List<screenmodel>. my action method is search(string types) and it should return the screensmodel that has the screenmodel list. in my unit test i want to check if the action methos returns the "List<screenmodel>" list

Comment: Are you using Stubs/Mocks? Or is this testing the database as well? Anyway I would say you just need to test that the list is not null and that count > 0.

Comment: Thanks what. I used Assert.IsTue(returnModel is screensmodel) since the list is inside the screens model class

Comment: Yeah, that's pretty much the same thing as using the "as" keyword.